# Cordova Native Apps redirection

Tags: android, cordova, native

I have a secure login apps build on Cordova.
I need a solution. 
when user login the apps. after verified logging, it's open another installed app that already installs the device.

means user open another's apps using the same authorized access details..

is it's possible? and how please help

Comment: Yes it is possible you need to have an account manager attached with your apps, both apps should share the same account manager, by successful adding account manager you can see it under your settings>accounts, once that is done few more code will be required to link both the apps by same account manager

Comment: Check out this link for reference: https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/android-single-account-multiple-application-prescription

Comment: this exactly not answers that's I want man.